# How to I enable https on my ec2 ami apache server

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have bought a an ssl certifcate from a respected authority on the internet. I am just having problems installing the certificate and enabling https on my server. I have only been given the certificate and the private key. How do I go about copying these files to my server and enabling https.

NOTE: I am running an amazon micro instance

Comment: Have you tried searching?

Comment: yeah, I found  a lot of the tutorials unhelpful

Comment: What OS/distro? What web server? Are you behind an ELB? What have you tried?

Comment: how about you read the question  and the details and you will see ... -_-

Answer (score 0):

First try to install mod_ssl on your server with the following command

```
 yum install mod_ssl
```

Once it's installed you can update your httpd configuration file with your SSL certificate details.

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/mydomain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/mydomain.key
```